# earth as a voltage reference

Tags: power, transformer, mains

Why is the neutral point of the alternator hooked up to the earth which makes all the voltages of the lines with reference to the earth. Doesn't this makes us more risky to the shocks?

I think we use earth as a return path in case of AC,Is it true??.

Why don't we use a configuration with a separate neutral wire(not hooked to the earth) for the return path of current,which makes less chances of shock(in that case we will have to touch both the live and the neutral wires to get a shock).

I have this doubt for a long time,I googled it up but it has made me more confused.
I'm sure you will get me out of it.
Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why don't we use a configuration with a separate neutral wire(not
>   hooked to the earth) for the return path of current,which makes us the
>   chances of shock(in that case we will have to touch both the live and
>   the neutral wires to get a shock).

We don't normally use an earth return. But we do normally connect neutral to earth at source. Why? There's a number of reasons, but here's my favourite: What would happen if we tried to have a floating non-ground-referenced system in real life? Numerous contact faults could accumulate without being detected, until sooner or later a contact to ground would occur, somewhere in the distribution system, suddenly rendering a whole lot of stuff elsewhere live and dangerous. Contrastingly, making sure that it is ground-referenced from the word go, means that any faults that do occur are immediately detected and blow out a circuit breaker before any harm is done. But you are right in so far as there is a trade-off - it's possible, though unlikely, for the earthing to make sure someone receives a fatal shock where without it there would be no hazard.

Comment: Suppose we have a ungrounded neutral system,then do we have charging currents still flowing into the ground ?

Answer (score 3):

With [a few exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-wire_earth_return), we don't intentionally use Earth as a return. Power systems are still kept near Earth potential for reasons of safety.

Consider: what would happen if the power distribution lines were in the neighborhood of 10,000V above Earth potential? While there still is a normal voltage between each of the lines, and an appliance connected only to these lines would function fine, what happens if you set the appliance on the ground? What happens if a person is holding the appliance, and simultaneously holding a cold water pipe?

The only thing protecting this person from a 10,000 VDC shock is some insulation which is hopefully intact. And of course, designing for a breakdown voltage > 10,000 V is rather difficult...

It's much simpler if you can take anything which might come in contact with a person and connect it directly to the Earth. Then you know if there's any fault which might expose a person to dangerous voltages, instead of shocking the user, the current will flow through this ground system and blow a circuit breaker.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](http://amasci.com/amateur/whygnd.html) helpful for understanding three-wire (hot/neutral/ground) power distribution. Here's the relevant excerpt:

> If you were to build your own electric power distribution system, you'd quickly discover some unexpected and strange effects. Sometimes your customers' appliances would fail for no apparent reason. And sometimes when you reached for a light switch, a foot-long spark would leap out to your hand and knock you senseless! What the heck?! It takes a huge DC voltage to make a foot-long spark. Why are high DC voltages appearing on your AC power lines?
>
> The sparks occur because of a little-known fact: all the world is a gigantic electrostatic generator. There is a flow of charge going on vertically everwhere on earth. Thunderstorms pump negative charge downwards, and the charge filters upwards everywhere else on earth. Depending on the height of your circuitry above the earth's surface, depending on the area covered by your wires, and depending on whether there was a thunderstorm above you at the time, there might be a fairly huge DC charge on your electrical distribution system. This charge might be several hundred volts; enough to zap computers and delicate electronics. Or... it might be many tens of thousands of volts, enough to create enormous sparks which jump across switches and leap out of wall outlets, wall switches, across transformer windings, etc. Your electric power system is acting like a sort of capacitive "antenna" which intercepts the feeble current coming from the sky and builds up a huge potential difference with respect to the earth.
>
> In addition to the above, you would find an unsettling phenomenon whenever lightning directly strikes your electrical distribution system. The lightning impulse-voltage spreads instantly throughout your whole network, which not only can explode every single appliance plugged in at the time, but can create lethal arcs many feet in length that reach out to "touch" your customers should they be anywhere near those wires within the walls.
>
> There is a simple solution to these problems: connect your system to the Earth. Drive some long metal rods into the dirt, and connect them to your wires. That way, lightning currents will be directed into the Earth rather than spreading throughout your power lines. Also, the clear-weather sky current can no longer build up a high voltage, if any excess charge immediately leaks into the earth.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, we do not use the earth as a return.

Under fault conditions, when a phase makes contact with the earth, fault currents flow to activate circuit protection to protect circuitry, property and personnel.  This makes it very easy to find faults, which is important from an operations point of view.  If you have a circuit that is regularly being tripped means there may be some operations or design issue with it.

If we used an insulated neutral and a fault to earth occurred, nothing would happen.  If an operator standing on the ground makes contact with another conductor would complete the circuit and get a shock.  So where was the original fault.  So the main reason we ground generators is safety.

After all if a fault occurs, the worst you are is in the dark.

There are other reasons like cost.  If you used a separate neutral, you'd have to run 4 wires instead of 3, with no real advantages.  As long as loads are balanced with three phase power, no neutral is required.

The marine environment uses 3 phase, ungrounded neutral.  The hull is not connected to the generators.  This means that if one phase makes contact with the hull, the power is not interrupted.  A ground fault occurs.  The main reason for this is to ensure the integrity of the power for safety purposes.  If a ship loses power while sailing in a channel would be a worse problem than losing the lights.  A ground fault must be cleared as soon as possible since the ship's hull is energized and a second fault will black out the ship or shock the person making contact.

Comment: you said,"If you used a separate neutral, you'd have to run 4 wires instead of 3, with no real advantages". Then what is used as a return path,in this case,along with three phases?

Comment: Phases are separated 120° so they act as the return paths.  If Phase A is +2A, then B & C are -1A. IA + IB + IC = 0.  Currents are vectors.

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cc/3_phase_AC_waveform.svg/2000px-3_phase_AC_waveform.svg.png